# How to pass parameters Active Model Serializer to another Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

having a problem with sending parameters. 
I have user_serializer and book_serializer and I want to send user_id to book_serializer inside user_serializer. Like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id

   has_many :books, serializer: BookSerializer, your_option_name: object.id
end
```

and then BookSerializer

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :test

  def test
     @instance_options[:your_option_name]
  end
end
```

but it's not working, getting null.

are there any ideas? great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments that you passed into `has_many ...` is actually used to create a [HasManyReflection](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/active_model/serializer/has_many_reflection.rb#L3) object which only accepts some very specific values and it also does not pass its argument any further.

The correct way to pass custom argument to nested serializers is through the [build_association](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/active_model/serializer/reflection.rb#L177) method or directly like below:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, books

  def books
    ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(object.books,  each_serializer: BookSerializer, your_option_name: object.id) 
  end
end
```