how to pass value from one serializer to other serializer?
So, I have three tables: patient, patient_segment, and segment.
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_segments
  has_many :segments, through: :patient_segments
end

class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_segments
  has_many :patients, through: :patient_segments
end

class PatientSegment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :segment
end

When I load the webpage, send data using PatientSerializer to display on the screen
class PatientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :patient_name,
             :birthday

  has_many :segments, serializer: SegmentAllSerializer
end

The SegmentAllSerializer looks like this:
class SegmentAllSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :hospital_id,
             :segment_name
end

Now, the data fetched on the frontend looks like this:
{
  "id": 1,
  "patient_name": "Steve",
  "birthday": "1986-11-02",
  "segments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "hospital_id": 1,
      "segment_name": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "hospital_id": 1,
      "segment_name": "b"
    }
  ] 
}

However, I need patient_id in SegmentSerializer. I am wondering if there's a way to get patient_id in SegmentSerializer.

Why do you need this when you already have the patient id as id? A Segment has_many :patients so this would be a collection under each segment. If you need a different Serializer you can always just create one. One for Segment as a standalone and one for when nested under a Patient

Yes there is, but before go with this approach, you need to seriously consider the question from @engineersmnky, since you are wasting resource to provide duplicate information. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106363/6894749

Thanks, I ended up resolving it by adding a new serializer
